# Is there anything to gain from having a 4k screen with 200% scaling vs. a FullHD screen?

Tags: display, fonts, display-resolution, hdpi

From what I understand, if I use a 4k (3840x2160) screen and configure it with a 200% scaling, it results in a "fake" FullHD (1920x1080). That means every pixel of the "FullHD" image gets displayed on four pixels (2x2) on the actual hardware screen, all displaying that same "virtual pixel".

**Is there any way at all for applications to make use of the extra pixels?** Especially with regards to font rendering. For example, could a text editor or an IDE (a JetBrains IDE in particular) make use of the extra hardware? I could imagine that the actual font rendering happens later in the rendering process. If e.g. an application says it uses a 16pt font, it leaves the rendering to the display manager, and the display manager knows that a 200% scaling is configured, so it renders the 16pt font as a 32pt font instead.

Note: I am talking about the "Scaling" option in Display Settings:

[image: ubuntu display settings]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes!

4k at 200% does actually not work as described in the question; to make it work like that you could simply operate the 4k screen with a FullHD resolution.

The 200% scaling works differently. Unfortunately I am not well versed enough in the inner workings of ubuntu's display management to be able to explain how exactly it works, but from my experimentations I can say that yes, it does indeed render most things in a hidpi mode, where fonts - and icons, in some cases - are rendered with a higher resolution. **Practically all of the "standard", builtin ubuntu GUI, including preinstalled applications, are rendered at double size, at the given resolution.** This includes the system settings, file browser,  I can provide a few images and highlight the differences between 100% and 200% scaling, to make things clearer.

#### The Dock

[image]
*Closeup comparison of a launcher icon in the dock. Left is 100% scaling, right is 200% scaling. The left half has been scaled up x2 in gimp for comparison purposes.*

Not much to add here. As you can see, the icon has visibly more detail with 200% scaling.

#### Gedit

[image]
*Closeup comparison of chrome and text body of the standard text editor. Left is 100% scaling, right is 200% scaling. The left half has been scaled up x2 in gimp for comparison purposes.*

Icons, labels and text body are all rendered with visibly more detail.

#### Gimp

[image]
*Comparison of GIMP, a foss image manipulation program. Left is 100% scaling, right is 200% scaling.*

Here it gets funny. Text elements are all rendered at twice the size, as expected. The icons however, are not, which might make them potentially too small to use on a very high dpi screen, despite the scaling. Notable is that the size of the image preview is not affected by the 200% scaling, which is certainly correct behaviour.

#### PyCharm

[image]
*Closeup comparison of PyCharm, an IDE developed by JetBrains. Above is 100% scaling, below is 200% scaling, respectively. The above has been scaled up x2 in gimp for comparison purposes.*

As the answer expresses interest in a JetBrains IDE specifically: PyCharm works very well with the 200% scaling. All user interface elements - icons, text elements, menu bars - are scaled up, rendered with visibly more detail.

Comment: Does this _actually mean_ that with 4K resolution without 200% scaling you'd get rendering like the examples on the left?! It strikes me a little odd that scaling would be necessary to take full exploit of a higher resolution, unless I knew more about the essence and history of the scaling feature.

Comment: @matanster it depends on how you want to make use of your 4k screen. Consider a 27" 4k screen (A) vs a 27" 1080p screen (B). If you want screen A to behave exactly like screen B, simply set the display resolution to 1080p. If you want 4x the usable screen space, set screen A to 4k display resolution at 100% scaling - everything will be rendered with the exact same pixel height and width, but A has 4x as many pixel as B. If you want UI elements to stay at the same physical size (actual cm/inch), but rendered visibly more crisp, set it to 4k display resolution and 200% scaling. hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks! it all makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

Some of my reasons:

- Smoother fonts (everything is scaled before rendering)
- Crisper icons (JetBrains IDEs in particular, many websites too)
- Sharper photos
- 4K videos
- Zoom out further in e.g. inkscape, before things start looking crap

Downsides:

- Not all programs do scale (Java Swing in particular)